# Multi-user, non-US personal finance and budget software

Tags: budget, software, norway

Hija,

I realize that there are any number of these questions on here. I didn't manage to find one that related to my specific situation, however.

First, I am outside mint.com territory.

Second, I am a member of a two-income household - we're not married, but we both have personal and shared expenses.

Third, we both operate on a number of different devices. A bunch of PCs and a Mac, some iPads, an iPhone, a Windows Phone...

This really makes me think about a web application, but I have not found a lot of good alternatives..

We would like to be able to keep track of our own bank cards and accounts, while both updating the things we have in common (credit card, loans, insurance for house and kids etc ..). The ability to track categories of spending as well as budget planning would be a nice bonus.

If it matters, we're located in Norway. We do not expect online banking integration, as that currently seems to be impossible here for security reasons (that is what they tell us, anyway).

**EDIT**: It doesn't HAVE to be multi-user as such - we're quite happy using the same user if we need to, as long as we can divide stuff into multiple accounts etc.

Comment: Challenging question, but relevant, because there are lots of people in that situation. Also, the fact that you are in Norway makes it a little more difficult, but there aren't many options in the U.S. either! Clarification please: Do you require a free service or is a fee-based service acceptable? Also, is the multiple device access a requirement, or could you limit yourself to Mac and/or PC's only?

Comment: Norway always makes everything more difficult. ;) Free would be preferred, but "freemium" or a reasonable price model is absolutely acceptable for me. Access on all devices would be a nice-to-have, but we could definitely live with Mac and/or PCs only - in that case, browser access would be highly preferred, but not a must either. With so few readily available options I don't want to make such a narrow definition of it that I exclude any possibilites. :)

Comment: Multiple currency support would be nice as well... this is sorely lacking in most personal finance products.

Answer (score 8):

My wife and I have been ridiculously happy with [YNAB](http://ynab.com). It's not "online," but syncs across our phones & computers using Dropbox.

It supposedly supports different locales and currencies, but I have never needed to try that out.

Comment: This needs more upvotes. Been using YNAB for over a year now with the wife. We have separate budgets and accounts, but a few of the same categories so we can divide shared expenses properly.

We're in Brazil, but YNAB is pretty currency-agnostic. Unless you need to deal with multiple currencies all the time, there's no problem.

So if your problem is just being outside of mint.com territory (as is mine), I'd say go with YNAB and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you are talking about. You may like

- http://www.chext.net/
- http://planwise.com/index.htm
- http://wealthorganiser.com/

Comment: Sorry about the slow reply, didn't stop by here for a while. Will check these out, thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Abhic for mentioning Chext. We're only available to users in the US and Canada right now but moving to other countries is something we have on the To-Do list. The biggest barrier is the cost of text messaging which is critical to our application today. Contact us and let us know if you're still interested. http://www.chext.net/contact-information/