# Good expense tracking and budgeting application for India

Tags: india, budget, software, expense-tracking

Could anyone recommend a good software application that I can use to keep track of my budget and expenses. Essentially at the end of every month, I find myself flabbergasted. Where did my money go?

I'm looking to set my finances in order. I think a good app is where the answer lies.

I'd like an application like Quicken which can link to my bank/credit card accounts also. I cannot use Quicken as it's not available in my country. Personally, I don't like to add every single transaction manually.

Ideally, the software would read my credit card and bank statements, automatically categorize my expenses and present come nice graphs and charts to help me understand my finances better. Also, it would work on the desktop and well as myriad other devices.

I found a relevant, if old thread [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14412/multi-user-non-us-personal-finance-and-budget-software). I am hoping there has been some more development in this area.

Answer (score 2):

"You Need A Budget" is a nice budgeting tool that works on the desktop.   It is more focused on manual entry and budgeting over auto-downloading and categorizing.   It does support downloading transactions from banks and then importing the transaction files.    You mentioned having "trust issues" with a bank and this would be safe as you don't enter your credentials into the app.   It also has a mobile app that works well.

Not exactly what you are looking for, but it would work in India and be safe if you have an untrustworthy bank and it would allow you to import transactions.

Answer (score 0):

For India there are very few services that are integrated with Bank & Card Accounts.
one such example is from myuniverse from Birla Group, other is money manager from ICICI Bank and also a service from Intuit

Comment: thanks for the info. Actually, I've test driven myuniverse. The user experience sucks. ICICI I haven't tried and don't want to try. I have trust issues with that bank. This service you mention from Intuit, I can't seem to find it anymore. I recall they had started such a service but I think they might have shut it down. Intuit's Quicken rocks, but not in India :(